# Run maven task thru IntelliJ: Maven resources plugin permission denied

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ to run a maven task but got error 
Maven resources plugin: Permission denied when copying some resource

How i can run that with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to permissions? Are you using the bundled `mvn` from IntelliJ?

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139236